# WebSphere Classloading issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I've deployed a `javaee web application in IBM WebSphere v8.5.5.1` and it has a Class `'InitialiseHelper'` which is present in `'WEB-INF/classes/test/initialse/helper/'` and also under `'WEB-INF/lib/helpers.jar'`. 
My application currently refers the class which is present in `'WEB-INF/lib/helpers.jar'`.

Server settings remain default.

How can I point the application to refer the class which is present in the location `'WEB-INF/classes/test/initialse/helper/'` instead of the current one?

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is a) impossible b) the way to further issues. Remove class file in the location where you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks @fnt. This works absolutely fine in Tomcat and I was expecting the same in WAS also. Can you tell me how class loading happens in WAS if I have duplicate classes?

Comment: You can set the application classloader policy to load classes from parent last. That will affect all your class loading though.

Comment: Check class loading order via console TroubleShooting > Class loader viewer . You will be able to see what is current loading order and from where is your class loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the classloader policy for your application. This is easier to find and do through an editor with support for WebSphere such as RAD, but it is a xml file which is deployed with the application.

Tha file is called `deployment.xml` and reside in `META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp` of the `EAR` file.

In there you should have a line called classloader with `mode="PARENT_LAST"` set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appdeployment:Deployment xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi" xmi:id="Deployment_1234567890123">
    <deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" xmi:id="ApplicationDeployment_1234567890123" startingWeight="1">
        <modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1234567890123" startingWeight="1" uri="MyWebApp.war" classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST"/>
        <classloader xmi:id="Classloader_1234567890123" mode="PARENT_LAST"/>
    </deployedObject>
</appdeployment:Deployment>
```